# Prestashop Webservice XML response parsingthe error

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to import my orders via API from my supplier to my PS 1.6.0.14 . Well, in localhost everything works fine but now at server I'm getting a big problem.

When trying to check if a customer exists or not I'm getting this error.

```
HTTP XML response is not parsable: array ( 0 => LibXMLError::__set_state(array( 'level' => 3, 'code' => 4, 'column' => 1, 'message' => 'Start tag expected, \'<\' not found ', 'file' => '', 'line' => 1, )), )
```

The function to check if a customer exists is this one:

```
function custExist($email_ws, $webService){
    $opt = [
        'resource'      => 'customers',
        'display'       => '[email]',
        'filter[email]' => '['.$email_ws.']',
        'limit'         => '1',
    ];

    //After this call, I've got the error.
    $xml = $webService->get($opt);

    if($email_ws == $xml->customers->customer->email)
        return FALSE;
    else
        return TRUE;

}
```

And finally, the webservice get function:

```
public function get($options)
{
    if (isset($options['url']))
        $url = $options['url'];
    elseif (isset($options['resource']))
    {
        $url = $this->url.'/api/'.$options['resource'];
        $url_params = array();
        if (isset($options['id']))
            $url .= '/'.$options['id'];

        $params = array('filter', 'display', 'sort', 'limit', 'id_shop', 'id_group_shop');
        foreach ($params as $p)
            foreach ($options as $k => $o)
                if (strpos($k, $p) !== false)
                    $url_params[$k] = $options[$k];
        if (count($url_params) > 0)
            $url .= '?'.http_build_query($url_params);
    }
    else
        throw new PrestaShopWebserviceException('Bad parameters given');

    $request = self::executeRequest($url, array(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET'));

    self::checkStatusCode($request['status_code']);// check the response validity
    return self::parseXML($request['response']);
}
```

Any tip to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've removed Friendly URL's from backend and now the error is bigger... If I enable debug mode for webservice call in response return I've got some HTML code, none JSON response. Kind weird...

```
RETURN HTTP BODY
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="es-es"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7" lang="es-es"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie8" lang="es-es"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js ie9" lang="es-es"><![endif]-->
<html lang="es-es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>PAGE TITLE</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Tienda creada con PrestaShop" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="tienda, prestashop" />
        <meta name="generator" content="PrestaShop" />
        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/img/favicon.ico?1482254072" />
.......
```

EDIT 2: Ok, problem founded. The URL for calling API Webservice, such as www.myprestashop.com/api/customers redirects me to my shop frontend.

Any idea? :(

Comment: have you checked the url "created" on the server for the connection? if it's not the correct one, it could cause a redirect to the main page or 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is something related to CHMOD permissions. If you're using AWS services, I'm 100% sure that's it.

well, no data come in from web service? Making other type of calls.

Comment: Ok, I've found the problem. For some reason, if you ckeck www.myprestashoppage.com/api/customers it redirects to the frontend of prestashop... Then no XML is in response, and we've all of HTML to XMLParse... What can I do?

Comment: Take a look on this https://community.bitnami.com/t/prestashop-1-7-webservice-bug-amazon-ec2-img/47286

Comment: I think is the same problem that I had 

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Comment: I've tried adding [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] to my .htaccess and nothing happens...

Comment: Did u put right after the line 8? Has to be this if it is redirecting. Must be something related to htaccess on the server side. Or very unlikely, something with your Server service.